# RequireJS: Set path to 'ignore'

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using a third-party library (through bower) that declares a dependency that I do not want (it's just styling).  Is it possible to set that dependency to 'ignore,' or some such value?

e.g.:

```
define(['jquery','dep_i_dont_want'], function(){...});
```

In require config:

```
paths: {
    'jquery': 'path/to/jquery',
    'dep_i_dont_want': 'ignore'
}
```

I would just require to look up 'dep_i_dont_want', see that it is ignored, and move on without including it or failing.  Is this possible?  I do not want to edit the third-party JS file.

For context, it doesn't seem that this is possible in the 'paths' object: none of undefined, null, '', 'ignore', 'blank', etc. seem to work.

I suppose I could just point it to a dummy module, but that feels like cheating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose I could just point it to a dummy module, but that feels like cheating.

Yes, this is what you have to do. There is no way to tell RequireJS "ignore this module". (There's the `empty:` scheme that you can give to `r.js` for modules loaded from CDNs but that's just for `r.js`' use during optimization.)

What you can do rather than setting a path to some sort of empty module is add this before your call to `require.config`:

```
define('dep_i_dont_want');
```

This will define the module in such a way that if it is required somewhere, its value will be `undefined`.